# How can I define a variable depending on the width of the screen?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I'm animating based on scroll position using TweenMax. The position at which I want to animate changes depending on the screen size. Is it possible to have a variable change based on the width of the screen?

I'm fairly new and using a lot of copy/paste solutions.
I have two rectangular divs beside each other that flip over like cards to display information on the back. When viewed on a mobile screen, these cards stack vertically instead of beside each other. This then changes the point at which I want to animate the flipping of the card.

The solution I've landed on is to change var sceneStart depending on a media query. This is just an idea for a solution to the problem.

This is what I have tried to no success.

```
var sceneStart2;
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)")) {
  sceneStart2 = 3500
} else {
  sceneStart2 = 2000
}
```

Expected result is on a large screen while divs are beside each other, card2 flips at 2000 but on a mobile screen card flips at 3500.

Actual result is that it breaks the flip entirely and doesn't function.

Comment: The `window.availWidth` gets you the screen's width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the `matches` property of the `MediaQueryList` returned by `matchMedia`:

```js
var sceneStart2;
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) {
  sceneStart2 = 3500
} else {
  sceneStart2 = 2000
}
console.log(sceneStart2);
```

Check out [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) for more info about `matchMedia`.

If you want this to update when the window resizes, you could move this logic into a function that gets called initially and on every window resize event:

```js
var sceneStart2;

calcSceneStart2();
window.addEventListener('resize', calcSceneStart2);

function calcSceneStart2() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)").matches) {
    sceneStart2 = 3500
  } else {
    sceneStart2 = 2000
  }
  console.log(sceneStart2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. And thank you for the additional reading. Now the follow up question is how can I have this work when you resize the window?

Comment: You could move this logic into a function and call that function whenever the window resizes. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: That didn't work when I put it into the full script. There isn't enough room in the comment box to paste the full code. Should I edit the original question and paste full script?